# Is the surface of the planet Mercury made of copper minerals?

Tags: transition-metals, astrochemistry

I have been looking at photographs of the planet Mercury, and I notices that in most of the pictures I have seen, the rocks on the surface seem to be covered in blue in green. From this, is it correct to say that the surface of Mercury is mostly made up of copper deposits?

Comment: The planet Mercury? No, the photos are very much grey. The surface is most likely covered mainly in silicates, i.e. rock.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)#Surface_geology

Comment: If you're referring to the picture @PrittBalagopal posted, these are not real colors but a color-coding for a height-representation.

Comment: @Fl.pf. Thanks for the insight but I already know that (I would need a heck of an imagination to think mercury is colored blue and orange!). I shared the link for the OP to search if he can find out about the surface of mercury minerals.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I wasn't saying that for you, I was guessing OP saw the picture you posted and thought it was real-color so I wanted to clear that up for him, not you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you probably fell into a trap concerning color-coding.

In reality, mercury is dark grey and mostly covered in silicate rocks/dust.

From a scientific point of view, the "real color" of an object like mercury is of little interest. What's more interesting, is it [topography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)#Surface_geology) etc. 
To make it easier to interpret data, man often uses color-coding (since our color-vision is quite ok) to communicate [different](https://jekko.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/pillars-of-creation-visible-inf-light.jpg) information about such [things](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/301837580_fig3_Figure-6-a-The-color-code-shows-the-mean-of-radiation-temperature-T-rad-throughout).

Or ist just about beauty: 
When you see pictures of nebulae like the [pillars of creation](https://www.google.de/search?q=pillars+of+creation&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiezpbNrLjUAhVJUBQKHULTDHoQ_AUICigB&biw=1680&bih=866) you notice they are in a lot of different colors. This is because a lot of the radiation is not in the visible spectrum, and you can "color-code" it to make it interesting to look at.